# How do you load KoLite using require.js?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, kolite

How do you load KoLite using require.js?
I've tried different things with requires (shim, export, init...)  and can never get around these errors
**KO is not defined** <- from inside the ko.DirtyFlag script
**can not call method DirtyFlag() on on undefined** <-from my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load koLite with requirejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276797/how-to-load-kolite-with-requirejs)

Comment: @PW Kad - Its a duplicate but none of the answers work

Comment: How do you load knockout? It is it pulled in before requireJS at the bottom of your page or you are loading it with requirejs? if so, is it available in the context of the module you are using it in? Put some code here so we don't have to guess what your project looks like

Comment: I want to load everything using require.js    The only way I have been able to make it work is to explicitly load knockout and kolite before requires.js but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

We have added support for RequireJS for all three libs now, you can use the latest version from [master](https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite).

Comment: Specifying 'how' would help the OP.  I am using the latest (requirejs supported) version and I am running into the same issues.

Comment: Can you give some more details on what issues you are running into?